# How can I create a Zend Framework controller/action url outside of controller?

Tags: php, zend-framework, command-line

I use the zend framework 1.11.2. I want to create URLs to controller actions that can be used inside email texts.

Within controllers I have done that with Zend_View_Helper_ServerUrl and Zend_View_Helper_Url like this:

```
$serverUrlHelper = new Zend_View_Helper_ServerUrl();
$unsubscribeUrl = $serverUrlHelper->serverUrl(
    $this->getHelper('url')->url(
       array(
           'module' => $this->getFrontController()->getDefaultModule(),
           'controller' => 'newsletter',
           'action' => 'unsubscribe',
           'email' => $email
       ),
       'default',   // the route
       true));
```

Now I want to do this not within a controller but instead from command line. I already managed to start a zend controller/action by following the steps described here [Running a Zend Framework action from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325338/running-a-zend-framework-action-from-command-line). But the `Application_Router_Cli` does not have an implementation for the `assemble` function. I never have done something deeply with zend routing. Could anyone could please give me an hint how to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of sub-classing from Zend_Controller_Router_Abstract in Application_Router_Cli (as instructed in that tutorial), subclass from Zend_Controller_Router_Rewrite. This should give you the assemble() function and allow you to use the URL Helper as you would normally use it in a web context.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what `default` routes means in your `application.ini` but i know your code must be like this :

```
   $serverUrlHelper = new Zend_View_Helper_ServerUrl();
   $unsubscribeUrl = $serverUrlHelper->serverUrl(
    $this->getHelper('url')->url(
       array(
           'module' => $this->getFrontController()->getDefaultModule(),
           'controller' => 'newsletter',
           'action' => 'unsubscribe',
           'email' => $email
       ),
       null,   // the route 
       true));
```

since your are assmble the route manually by using  array of `module , controller , view`

so the second param of the url view help must be null , 
and in the case you have a route in your `application.ini` and you want this  link to follow that route your function must be like this :

```
 $serverUrlHelper = new Zend_View_Helper_ServerUrl();
   $unsubscribeUrl = $serverUrlHelper->serverUrl(
    $this->getHelper('url')->url(
        null,
       "email",   // aka the route name
       true));
```

hopefully i explain it in easy way

Answer (score 1):

[optima1's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10645790/60887) got me started on the right track but I wanted to share some additional steps I needed to make the `url()` and `serverUrl()` view helpers work in a CLI script.

### Detect Environment

The first challenge is defining the server environment.  This is often in the .htaccess or a FastCGI environment variable, so it's not loaded in the CLI.  I use an INI file to map the server name to the environment.

```
[ServerEnvironments]
PROD-SERVER = "production"
STAGE-SERVER = "staging"
MY-LOCAL-VM = "development"
```

Then my CLI script sets the `APPLICATION_ENV` constant accordingly.

```
$iniConfig = parse_ini_file(rtrim(dirname(__FILE__), '\/') . '/servers.ini', TRUE);
$environment = isset($iniConfig['ServerEnvironments'][getenv('COMPUTERNAME')])
             ? $iniConfig['ServerEnvironments'][getenv('COMPUTERNAME')]
             : 'production';
defined('APPLICATION_ENV') || define('APPLICATION_ENV', $environment);
```

### Populate Server Superglobal

The rest of the script continues normally as shown in [David's example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2329434/60887).  However, I bootstrap all resources (an empty call to `bootstrap()`).  I also include an additional INI file when instantiating `Zend_Application`, like so:

```
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    array('config' => array(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini',
                            APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/cli.ini')));
```

The CLI INI file will store request information that is normally provided by the web server.

```
[production]
cli.request.serverVars.HTTPS = "on"
cli.request.serverVars.HTTP_SCHEME = "https"
; Host name, including port if non-standard.
cli.request.serverVars.HTTP_HOST = "example.com"
; Absolute path to the web root.  Exclude trailing slash.
cli.request.serverUrl = "https://example.com"
; Relative path from web root to the Zend Framework application.  Include leading slash.
cli.request.baseUrl = "/ZF"

[staging : production]
cli.request.serverUrl = "https://stage.example.com"
cli.request.serverVars.HTTP_HOST = "stage.example.com"

[development : production]
cli.request.serverUrl = "https://dev.example.com:4433"
cli.request.serverVars.HTTP_HOST = "dev.example.com:4433"
```

After the call to `bootstrap()`, the CLI script populates the `$_SERVER` superglobal.  Note that during bootstrapping, I store the application config in the `Zend_Registry`.

```
$config = Zend_Registry::get('config');
foreach($config->cli->request->serverVars as $name => $value) {
    $_SERVER[$name] = $value;
}
```

### Build URI and Dispatch

The last hurdle is that I use custom routes instead of `/module/controller/action`, and the latter format is disabled (`Zend_Controller_Router_Rewrite::removeDefaultRoutes()`).  So the CLI script needs to specify the route rather than the module, controller, and action.

```
$route = 'My/Custom/Route';

$spoofedUri = $config->cli->request->serverUrl
            . rtrim($config->cli->request->baseUrl, '/') . '/'
            . $route;
$request = new Zend_Controller_Request_Http($spoofedUri);
$request->setBaseUrl($config->cli->request->baseUrl);

$front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$front->setRequest($request)
      ->setResponse(new Zend_Controller_Response_Cli())
      ->dispatch();
```

This may not solve every discrepancy between web and CLI requests (you may need to populate more `$_SERVER` variables) but it fixed `url()` and `serverUrl()` for me.

Answer (score 0):

In your CLI script, if you make sure to bootstrap a view resource:

`$application->getBootstrap()->bootstrap(array('db', 'mail', 'view'));`

then, you can use the same view helpers as always, right?