# How to connect to DB, when running via command line

Tags: php, zend-framework, command-line, zend-db

When I run zend framework project from browser, everything is OK, it connects to DB.

When I run project from command line it can't connect to DB and it throws an error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory' in
>   /usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:129

I have used
[Running a Zend Framework action from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2325338/457033) 's answers ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/4706966/457033 )

It's my `application.ini` file's db part

```
phpSettings.mysql.default_socket=/usr/local/zend/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock

resources.db.adapter = "PDO_MYSQL"
resources.db.params.host = "localhost"
resources.db.params.port = 3306
resources.db.params.username = "root"
resources.db.params.password = "root"
resources.db.params.dbname = "iteam"
resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true
resources.db.params.charset = "utf8"
```

Answer (score 1):

Copy the content of application.ini in your php.ini file, this should work fine.