# Standalone PHP Application Zend Framework 1.11

Tags: php, zend-framework

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Running a Zend Framework action from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325338/running-a-zend-framework-action-from-command-line)

I want to create a PHP application using Zend Framework (version 1.11). It's basically for carrying out some routine tasks on a mail server, the service will get ran via a cron job.

However, because it will possibly be nice in the future to have some sort of HTML based monitoring system I want to have the the layout capabilities available.

So really there's two questions:

1. How do I disable Zend Framework from rendering the view when I am running from command line?
2. And how would I generally go about also building in an interface should I visit a specific url?

Thanks in advance for your advice.

Comment: Which version of Zend Framework do you use?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325338/running-a-zend-framework-action-from-command-line

Comment: That link provided me with the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4706966/387761 thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I am doing these daily tasks automatically such as  :

1. sending out invoices
2. sending sms + email notifications
3. doing some house keeping stuff [caching + moving files + archiving.... etc  ]

I got this idea http://www.davidcaunt.co.uk/2010/02/25/easy-command-line-scripts-with-zend-application/ and i had  extended to do manage tasks + add tasks + delete tasks  + process tasks.

usually I don't render any view , just calling functions and classes to tasks + parameters

Comment: Thanks but I really needed the ability to serve a web ui should the application be requested via a browser. Found my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4706966/387761

Comment: Using the method from @tawfekov answer still allow you to have a Web UI, the selective bootstrap method is useful for running cron since you don't have to initialize the full Zend Framework stack (which is pretty heavy). From there you can still interact with the needed components of Zend (Db, Mail, etc.). When you are ready to build your Web UI, you can then go and use the full MVC stack

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, you could create an action that can receive a parameter if the link is requested via your cronjob.  Something like this:

```
public function somepageAction() {
    if($this->_getParam('requestedByCronJob') {
        $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
        $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
    }

    //Add the code here
    //The view/scripts/controller/somepage.phtml will be loaded if the parameter requestedbycronjob was not passed

}
```