# Zend_Controller_Router_Exception: Route default is not defined

Tags: php, zend-framework, url, zend-route, zend-view

In my app with several modules, I have a method that sends an email, the text use the url view helper to build a link. If I execute this method via browser everything works correctly, but if I run this method via a cron via shell I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Controller_Router_Exception' with message 'Route default is not defined' in /path/ZendFramework-1.12.1/library/Zend/Controller/Router/Rewrite.php on line 318

Zend_Controller_Router_Exception: Route default is not defined in /path/ZendFramework-1.12.1/library/Zend/Controller/Router/Rewrite.php on line 318
```

Browsing the web I found this solution: http://www.dragonbe.com/2012/11/route-default-is-not-defined.html

If I do what I said in the blog error does not occur more, but at this point the generated link and 'missing the protocol and hostname, writes me a link to only the controller and action, such as "/controller/action/foo/bar"

Could you help me?

thanks

---

**Edit**

This is how I run my cron jobs:

structure:

```
app/
app/application
.. stuff ...
app/scripts/
app/scripts//bootstrap.php
app/scripts//cronjobs.php
```

app/scripts//bootstrap.php

```
<?php
// Define path to application directory
define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application/'));

// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(
    implode(PATH_SEPARATOR,
        array(
            realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
            get_include_path())));

if (isset($zendOptions)) {

    // using Zend_Console_Getopt to parse environment to load
    require_once 'Zend/Console/Getopt.php';

    try {
        $getOpt = new Zend_Console_Getopt($zendOptions);
        $getOpt->parse();
    } catch (Zend_Console_Getopt_Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
        echo $e->getUsageMessage();
        exit(1);
    }

    if ($getOpt->getOption('h')) {
        echo $getOpt->getUsageMessage();
        exit(0);
    }
    // Define application environment
    define('APPLICATION_ENV',
    $getOpt->getOption('e') ? $getOpt->getOption('e') : 'production');
} else {
    // Define application environment using getenv
    define('APPLICATION_ENV',
    getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production');
}

// define APPLICATION_BOOTSTRAP if not defined
if (!defined('APPLICATION_BOOTSTRAP')) {
    define('APPLICATION_BOOTSTRAP', true);
}

// Define standard config file
define('APPLICATION_CONFIG', APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini');

/** Zend_Application */
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

// Init a Zend_Application
$zendApplication = new Zend_Application(APPLICATION_ENV, APPLICATION_CONFIG);
if (APPLICATION_BOOTSTRAP) {
    $zendApplication->bootstrap();
}
```

app/scripts/cronjobs.php

```
<?php
// define options for script
$zendOptions = array(
    'environment|e=w' => 'Environment to use as specified in application.ini (default production)',
    'test|t' => 'test cron',
    'help|h' => 'Show program usage');

// bootstrap application object (default true, put to false
// if you need to bootstrap only single resources
define('APPLICATION_BOOTSTRAP', true);

// parse the options and bootstrap application if required
require_once realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/bootstrap.php');

/* start your script here, you'll have the following vars: */
/* @var $zendApplication Zend_Application initialized Zend_Application object */
/* @var $getOpt Zend_Console_Getopt a getopt parsed object */

error_reporting(E_ALL);

if ($getOpt->getOption('t')) {

    $vhUrl = new Zend_View_Helper_Url();
    $url = $vhUrl->url(array('controller' => 'foo', 'action' => 'bar'));
    Zend_Debug::dump($url);
}
```

the debug print '/foo/bar'

Comment: this may help some as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325338/running-a-zend-framework-action-from-command-line

Comment: to run my cron, use Zend_Console_Getopt, I know how it works. What I do not understand is why the generated link is missing the hostname?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include more info about your cron script - does it run the application bootstrap? And can you show how are you calling the URL helper?

Comment: I add how I run my cron jobs.

Comment: Okay so what's the issue? Despite its name, the URL helper only ever outputs the path, it doesn't include a hostname (except possibly when you are using hostname routes).

Comment: I want the output to be `http://myHostname.com/foo/bar`. how should I do?

Comment: `$url = 'http://myHostname.com'.$vhUrl->url(array('controller' => 'foo', 'action' => 'bar'));`?

Comment: eh no, man! as I have already said, the view helper I use it in a method that also uses a page called via a browser and in that case the view helper returns the full url complete. I need to understand what and how should I configure to averere the same comportamente to view helper called via cron.

Answer (score 3):

**I found the solution**

application.ini

```
[production]
baseUrl = mydomain.com

[development : production]
baseUrl = mydomain.dev

[testing : production]
baseUrl = mydomain.test
```

Bootstrap.php

```
/**
 * Default Routes
 */
protected function _initDefaultRoutes()
{
    $frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $frontController->getRouter()->addDefaultRoutes();
    $options = $this->getOptions();
    $frontController->setBaseUrl('http://' . $options['baseUrl']);
}
```

and now work!

Comment: You did exactly what is not recommended to do... From the source: `Do not use the full URI when providing the base. The following are
     * examples of what not to use:
     * - http://example.com/admin (should be just /admin)`

Answer (score 0):

By default helper `Zend_View_Helper_Url` uses `Zend_Controller_Router_Rewrite` which doesn't include hostname and protocol (see `Zend_Controller_Router_Rewrite::assemble`).

However, if you want to pass `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` when you execute scripts from the cli this can be done using following construction:

```
HTTP_HOST=example.com php /path/to/cronjob.php
```

Later, if you want to get your current server url, you can use `Zend_View_Helper_ServerUrl`

Example:

```
<?php
// cronjob.php
$serverUrl = new Zend_View_Helper_ServerUrl();
var_dump($serverUrl->serverUrl());
```

// outputs: `string(18) "http://example.com"`

Comment: thanks for your contribution, but I found an elegant solution, post it now!

Comment: I tried to do what I say, but it does not work the same as I would like. From my cron call a method in a model where I use `$this->url(...);` and it always prints only the controller and action. By doing this the link in the email that you send is corrupted!

Comment: what stops you from prepending `$this->serverUrl()` before `$this->url(...);` in your views ?

Comment: it works when I call the method via cron, but if I call the method via browser then I find a link like this: `http://mydomain.devhttp//mydomain.dev/controller/action/` how can I fix this?

Comment: this: `http//mydomain.dev/controller/action/`

Comment: this is var_dump or link what you see in the browser ? and how  do you call it ? $this->url() with what arguments ?

Comment: in my method: `$vhUrl = new Zend_View_Helper_Url(); $urlShow = $vhUrl->url(array('controller' => 'controller_name', 'action' => 'action_name', 'id' => $this->id)); var_dump($urlShow);`